# Find a character in a string using Powershell?

Tags: sql, string, powershell, substring, character

I know I could use `Contains` to find it but it doesn't work.

Full Story: 
I have to get the PartNo, Ver, Rev from SQl db and check if they occur in the first line of the text file. I get the first line of the file and store it in `$EiaContent`.
The PartNo is associated with MAFN as in `$partNo=Select PartNo Where MAFN=xxx.` Most of the time MAFN returns one PartNo. But in some cases for one MAFN there could be multiple PartNo. So the query returns multiple PartNo(PartNo_1,PartNo_2,PartNo_3,and PartNo_4) but only one of these will be in the text file.

The issue is that each of these PartNo. is treated as a single character in PowerShell. `$partNo.Length` is 4. Therefore, my check `If ($EiaContent.Contains("*$partNo*"))` fails and it shouldn't in this case because I can see that one of the PartNo is mentioned in the file. Also, `Contains` wouldn't work if there was one PartNo. I use `like` as in `If ($EiaContent -like "*$partNo*")` to match the PartNo and it worked but it doesn't work when there are multiple PartNo.

Data type of `$partNo` is string and so is `$EiaContent`. The data type of PartNo. in SQL is varchar(50) collation is `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`
I am using PowerShell Core 7.2 and SQL 2005

Code:

```
    $EiaContent = (Get-Content $aidLibPathFolder\$folderName\$fileName  -TotalCount 1)
    Write-host $EiaContent
    #Sql query to get the Part Number 
    $partNoQuery = "SELECT PartNo FROM [NML_Sidney].[dbo].[vMADL_EngParts] Where MAFN = $firstPartTrimmed"
    $partNoSql = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query $partNoQuery
    #Eliminate trailing spaces
    $partNo = $partNoSql.PartNo.Trim()
    If ($EiaContent.Contains("*$partNo*")) {
       Write-Host "Part Matches"
    }
    Else {
       #Send an email stating the PartNo discrepancy 
    }
```

Thank you in advance to those who try to help.

**EDIT**
Screenshot
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIqJB.png

`A1023 A1023MD C0400 C0400MD` is the output of the variable `$partNo` and `O40033( C0400 REV N VER 004, 37 DIA 4.5 BRAKE DRUM OP3 )` is the output of the variable `$EiaContent`

Comment: `.Contains` doesn't fail because _Length is 4_, it fails because is checking everything as literal (`*` is not considered as a wildcard but as a literal asterisk).

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for replying.  I have tried  `.Contains`, `-Contains` with `"$partNo"`,  `$partNo` and none of them work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the query returns multiple PartNo(PartNo_1,PartNo_2,PartNo_3,and PartNo_4) but only one of these will be in the text file.

> `A1023 A1023MD C0400 C0400MD` is the output of the variable `$partNo` and `O40033( C0400 REV N VER 004, 37 DIA 4.5 BRAKE DRUM OP3 )` is the output of the variable `$EiaContent`

So you first have to [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split) `$partNo` and then for each sub string of `$partNo`, search for it in `$EiaContent`:

```
If ($partNo -split ' ' | Where-Object { $EiaContent.Contains( $_ ) }) {
   Write-Host "Part Matches"
}
```

This is the generic form that most people are used to. We can simplify the query using the unary form of `-split` (as we split on the default separator) and use the intrinsic array method [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#where) which is faster as it does not involve pipeline overhead.

```
If ((-split $partNo).Where{ $EiaContent.Contains( $_ ) }) {
   Write-Host "Part Matches"
}
```

As correctly [noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71819878/find-a-character-in-a-string-using-powershell/71820292#comment126915929_71819878), wildcards are *not* supported by the [`.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0) string method.

Wildcards are supported only by the PowerShell `-like` operator. The following example is just for educational purposes, I wouldn't use it in your case as `.Contains()` string method is simpler and faster.

```
If ((-split $partNo).Where{ $EiaContent -like "*$EiaContent*" }) {
   Write-Host "Part Matches"
}
```

Note that `-contains` would *not* be suitable here. A common misconception is that `-contains` does a substring search, when the LHS operand is a string. It doesn't! The operator tests whether a *collection* (such as an array) on the LHS contains the value given on the RHS.

Comment: @zett42Thank you for replying. I tried both your suggestions `If ($partNo.Contains($EiaContent)){}` and `If ($partNo -like "*$EiaContent*"){}`  but they don't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Brute Please show values of the variables before the `if` stdtement.

Comment: I edited my question and added a screenshot of the output. This is what is going on  `A1023 A1023MD C0400 C0400MD` is the output of the variable `$partNo` and `O40033( C0400 REV N VER 004, 37 DIA 4.5 BRAKE DRUM OP3 )` is the output of the variable `$EiaContent`.

Comment: @Brute I see. Could you please add these samples from your comment to the question? This is important information for answering the question.